# starting MongoDB process best practice?

Tags: mongodb

so I'm getting started on MongoDB and I can't seem to find any documentation on the best practice for how the MongoDB process should be run.  Ideally, I would like it to use the `/etc/mongodb.conf` file for it's parameters that's setup with a replica set (primary, secondary, arbiter).

`/etc/mongodb.conf` is owned by root and my db is owned by the mongodb user.  I login as user ubuntu and I don't know how to start the mongodb process automatically as the mongodb user.  I have been using root to execute `mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf` but there's a better way to do this.  I know I'll need to modify `/etc/mongodb.conf` to allow the mongodb user to access it and that's not a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not change permissions of `/etc/mongodb.conf`. It's not necessary. Open this file with the root user and personalize it according to your needs.

To start MongoDB with the **ubuntu** user, type one of the following commands.

```
sudo service mongodb start
```

Or

```
sudo invoke-rc.d mongodb start
```

Or

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mongodb start
```

In this way MongoDB will end up running as the **mongodb** user.